# Manage GUI and logic interaction in Python

Tags: python, presentation-layer, business-layer

I developed a big python project, that does specific tasks. Later on I decided to add a graphical user interface for it.

```
├── GUI
|
└── myScript
```

Let's say the GUI has a "Start" button. When clicking on it, we start the business logic that is located in "myScript".

Currently I implemented the interaction this way:

Inside the `GUI`:

```
os.chdir("../myScript")
main.start() #calling the business function from myScript
os.chdir("../GUI")
```

I needed to add os.chdir because I had to deal with a lot of file reading and writing inside `myScript`. (I used absolute paths to find files)

I don't feel like this is the best way to link the presentation layer to the business layer. Is there a better way to do this in Python?

Comment: *"I needed to add `os.chdir` because I had to deal with a lot of file reading and writing inside `myScript`."* -- Please elaborate on that. What kind of files are you talking about? Maybe temp files? Why do they live in the application folder instead of a dedicated folder like `/tmp` or `~/.myScript`?

Comment: The only thing that's wrong with that is that the business logic ASSUMES a given working directory.  If it needs files that are in its same directory, it should use `os.dirname(__file__)` to figure out where it is located, and use that as its starting path.

Comment: What kind of GUI are you using tkinter or pyQt any way why don't you use open dir dialog  to get the parent dir path then work with sub dirs

Comment: @wjandrea it's just normal files that I need to read and write in inside the application.

Comment: @Stefano pyqt, I'll have a look into that, thanks

Comment: @TimRoberts, I'll have a look into that, thanks

Comment: @Gaston What do you mean by "normal files"? Why do you need to write to files inside the application folder?

Comment: Sorry not normal files. To be more precise, the application folder contains temporary files, like you said that will be modified then moved to another destination.